# Will 'http:url' work for all browsers and devices?

Tags: javascript, mobile, browser, web

In making a function that validates a user URL and prepends http: at the front, I have to take cases of www, https and // into account as being valid urls. The way I have it written now (see below), I only prepend http: , so that cases of **//stackoverflow.com** don't turn into **http: ////stackoverflow.com**.

This means that a url like stackoverflow.com becomes **http:stackoverflow.com**.

In Firefox and Chrome, this works just fine, but these URLS will be clicked from a variety of browsers and devices. **Is it something that'll work universally?** It'll be easy to rewrite this check for a // case, but I'm interested in the answer.

Prepend method:

```
function prependHTTPtoWebURL() {
    var url = (el('org_website').value);
    var httpVar;
    var testFor;

    if (url) {// If there's a website URL value
        testFor = url.toLowerCase();
        if (testFor.indexOf("http") != 0){
            httpVar = 'http:'; //add it
            url = httpVar + url;
         el('org_website').value = url;
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whether they work or not should be tested by you. Whether you should do it like that: h*%l no. This is not a programming questions, but a question in the category of: I don't want to fix my code and make it sane will this crappy solution work?

Comment: If your url is `myhttp.com/mypage.html` then your function will not work.. you need to make sure the http is also at the beggining (not just if it exists or not)

Comment: i would just use a temp A tag to parse and coearce any and all input into a valid url instead of doing all the legwork myself: x=document.createElement("a"); x.href=url; alert(x.href);

Comment: @dandavis That won't work in some cases (YotamOmer's example)

Comment: @ian: sure it will, a valid url must come out. if that's not the one they wanted, they can fix it before submitting...

Comment: @dandavis How is this remotely close to what the OP wants? http://jsfiddle.net/tHE2E/

Comment: @PeeHaa It's impossible for me to test whether 'http:stackoverflow.com' works on devices I don't *have*. Your comment was uninformative and caustic. Thankfully, I got what I wanted to know from other folks. "Dunno, but just don't do it that way."

Comment: @Ian: i'm saying that as a final "validation", it a good idea for any url-rewriting function to parse and re-gen the resulting URL to make sure it's valid no matter what.

Comment: @Kate It would also be impossible for us to test it on all devices isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try playing with regex. Check this code for instance:

```
var someurl = "www.google.com";
var otherurl = "google.com";
var anotherurl = "//google.com";

function prependHTTPtoWebURL(url) {
    var newurl = url.replace(/^(http)?(:)?(\/\/)?/i,'');
    return 'http://' + newurl;
}

console.log(prependHTTPtoWebURL(someurl));
console.log(prependHTTPtoWebURL(otherurl));
console.log(prependHTTPtoWebURL(anotherurl));
```

The ouput in console.log will be:

```
http://www.google.com
http://google.com
http://google.com
```

Since you are specifying a subdomain (www) on the first one, that is respected. It avoids ending with four diagonals, like `http:////`. If your url was something like `:google.com`, it would also fix it correctly.

You can see it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/zRBUj/

*Edit*: Adding the `/i` Kate mentioned.

Comment: While this doesn't exactly answer my question of "Does 'http:stackoverflow.com' work as a valid a href= everywhere, it is a beautifully elegant solution, which I will probably use since the answer to my question seems to be 'no'.

Comment: EDIT: The only difference is my adding /i for the Regex to make it case insensitive.

Comment: Oh yes, the `/i` is important, I have edited the answer. Also, the answer to the question if it is valid is 'no', but it *could* work on some user agents. Dunno XD

Answer (score 0):

Change http: to http://

See these links for more info:

[Anatomy of a URL](http://moz.com/blog/seo-cheat-sheet-anatomy-of-a-url)

[How the web works](http://www.garshol.priv.no/download/text/http-tut.html)